# Has anyone managed to get an EU green pass based on a CDC card?

Tags: covid-19

So we know that different EU countries have different approaches to proof of vaccination and some do not accept the CDC card in the first place... but the way the system was supposed to work was that if you got into one of the participating countries, that country would issue you with a Digital Green Pass which would then be accepted by all the others.

Has anyone managed to get a DGP this way, or maybe tried and been refused?

Comment: This is now called: [EU Digital COVID Certificate  (EDCC)](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/coronavirus-response/safe-covid-19-vaccines-europeans/eu-digital-covid-certificate_en#how-can-citizens-get-the-certificate) and *allow[s] the possibility to extend to compatible certificates issued in third countries.* This would have to be done by someone who can issue a EDCC.

Comment: This is more likly to be successfull if the **CDC Vaccination Card** has been filled out in the same mannor as an [International Certificate of Vaccination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Certificate_of_Vaccination_or_Prophylaxis#Required_components) *The form must be fully completed in English or French by a medical practitioner or authorized health worker and **must include the official stamp of the administering centre**.*

Comment: In Germany, Apotheke (pharmacy) are allowed to issue an EDCC and accept an *International Certificate of Vaccination* as proof. This is probably the best option.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The US Army has some information on this process for service members stationed in Germany who want to get a EU digital COVID Vax certificate. According to this, the steps are as follows:

1. Locate a pharmacy ("Apotheke" in Germany"). Not all pharmacies offer the digital certificates. The website https://www.mein-apothekenmanager.de/ allows you to find ones that offer this service specifically (in Germany). Under "Serviceleistungen" select "Digitales Impfzertifikat".
2. Take your CDC card to this pharmacy. You will also need to present a valid photo ID, best chances of success would probably be a passport.
3. Receive the paper certificate with a QR code.
4. Use the CovPass app to scan this QR code.

[Source](https://www.army.mil/article/247734/optional_how_to_get_the_eu_covid_vax_digital_certificate_in_germany)

Comment: You can also use other apps to scan and store your certificate, e.g. the [Corona-Warn-App](https://www.coronawarn.app/) that is also used to track exposure to other people using the app and the [Luca App](https://www.luca-app.de/) (website only in German) that is usually used to digitally "check-in" to restaurants, cinemas etc.

Comment: The answer should note that you absolutely must be a resident of Germany for this to be an option. (I know because this is what I was told when I tried)

Comment: @DreamConspiracy https://www.stuttgartcitizen.com/news/voluntary-digital-apps-provide-additional-proof-of-vaccination-status/ suggests otherwise and notes: "_If, for some reason, the pharmacy is unable to provide the certificate with the provided documentation, try a different one._"

Comment: @DreamConspiracy is there any source for that other than your personal experience at one pharmacy? I could see this being an issue, and like Tim says, there would be a good chance this is just how one person at one pharmacy interprets the rules. Some pharmacies tend to be very old school and buraucratic.

Comment: Honestly I’d give a shot at 10 different pharmacies if I have to. Ones vaccination status has absolutely nothing to do with citizenship or residency (the virus doesn’t care) so as long as you can brute force your way into a certificate it’s all good.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy [Regulation 2021/953 - EU Digital COVID Certificate](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32021R0953#d1e810-1-1) Article 8: *those authorities **may**, upon request, issue a vaccination certificate as referred to in point (a) of Article 3(1) to the person concerned*. No meantion of citizenship or residence requirement. The coresponding German law: *in particular to verify the identity of the vaccinated person and the authenticity of the vaccination documentation*. So it is the pharmacist *choice* to do so or not.

Comment: And this vaxx passport would be permissible in other Schengen countries, regardless of the fact that it originates from a CDC card? I'm very curious if this process can be done without already being in the EU...