# How to get EU "Green Pass" showing full vaccination if vaccinated outside EU?

Tags: europe, france, covid-19, eu

According to news reports like [this one](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/jul/26/covid-more-eu-states-restrict-venue-access-unvaccinated-people), to enter bars, restaurants in countries like France, Italy, Ireland and Germany, you need proof of vaccination. I am double vaccinated, but was so outside of EU. I have my proof, but how do I get that proof in a form useful in these countries? i.e Can I download the French Covid app and somehow enter my status? Same goes for other countries.

BTW, I am also an EU (Italy) citizen, but I am not a resident.

Comment: Does https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166758/are-there-eu-countries-that-allow-foreign-residents-to-obtain-the-eu-vaccination answer your question?

Comment: @Relaxed It might after a while? Right now it seems very focused on non-EU citizens and getting the pass "from afar", but it's as close as I've seen!

Comment: I don't think citizenship matters much. It is about getting the certificate before landing. If you're fine taking care of it in person, there are options in Germany and Austria it seems.

Comment: @Relaxed Do you know if that then allows EU-wide use? The passes seem somewhat country specific. So going to Germany to get a pass to then spend time in France doesn't seem possible?

Comment: The applications may be country specific, but the **EU Digital COVID Certificate** is not. The *International Certificate of Vaccination* will still remain as proof that most people who need to check these things are most familiar with. They should, however, be properly filled out otherwise the might not be accepted. *The form must be fully completed in English or French by a medical practitioner or authorized health worker and **must include the official stamp of the administering centre**.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's not generally the case. For example, in France, you cannot easily get an *International Certificate of Vaccination* for a Covid vaccine and they don't help at all to enter a museum. This is completely unrelatetd to the EU Digital Covid certificate, which, as expected, can be issued for a single injection or for a test.

Comment: @hamburgermenu Yes, it is, the whole point of the pass is to allow cross-border use. If you obtain a German pass based on a full vaccination course that's at least a week in the past, it will be accepted in France for all purposes.

Comment: @Relaxed Thank you for all the follow up - there's a lot of little things and I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Are there EU countries that allow foreign residents to obtain the EU vaccination certificate?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166758/are-there-eu-countries-that-allow-foreign-residents-to-obtain-the-eu-vaccination) deals with obtaining a certificate based on vaccination abroad. It's almost impossible at the moment.

Note that in France, at least, you do not need a proof of vaccination to go anywhere, it's also possible to get the required digital certificate through a test. Getting a test every 48 to 72 hours is therefore the only solution for tourists in France at the moment.

Comment: [This](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/jul/12/france-mandates-covid-health-pass-for-restaurants-and-cafes) seems to suggest France does require it?

Comment: @hamburgermenu Not quite yet but that wasn't my point. The confusion is on the nature of the “it”: health pass is required (e.g. to enter a museum) but it can be obtained using EITHER a proof of vaccination, proof of recovery or proof of a recent test. Vaccination as such is not required except for healthcare personnel. That's also what this article explains. Of course, getting a test every other day is inconvenient and costs money but it remains possible.

Comment: Got it. Yes, I asked about the Health Pass, though was a bit loose in my wording. But getting a test every 2 days didn't even register to me as a consideration. I'm vaccinated and an EU citizen, just wanted to know if I could hook into the pass schemes yet

Comment: Or, in other words: the “green pass” (EU Covid Digital certificate) doesn't show full vaccination. It documents vaccination (even one injection), tests (PCR or not) and recovery. It's up to each state to set requirements based on this info. For example, France requires a full course of vaccination to be exempted from tests. A certificate showing only one injection (for a vaccine requireing two) wouldn't help you in this situation. But you can still get a pass.

Comment: @hamburgermenu I got that. The answer is no, there are more details in the other question. Beyond thatt, I still thought it was useful to dispell the confusion regarding what the exact requirements are and the alternatives that do exist, however inconvenient they might be.