# Does a French Pass Sanitaire based on a UK vaccine constitute an EU Digital Covid Certificate?

Tags: uk, france, covid-19, eu

I'm a UK citizen and resident looking to travel to a handful of EU countries including France in the next few months.

The EU-wide [Digital Covid Certificate](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/coronavirus-response/safe-covid-19-vaccines-europeans/eu-digital-covid-certificate_en) should be valid as proof of vaccination in all EU countries, but people vaccinated in the UK aren't eligible.

France has announced they do accept UK vaccination certificates, and I was able to import mine into the French TousAntiCovid app and get a *Pass Sanitaire*. What's not clear to me: does this count as a full EU Digital Covid Certificate? If not, is it possible to generate one from TousAntiCovid, **or obtain one any other way based on a UK vaccination**?

[This French government page](https://uk.ambafrance.org/Applying-for-a-COVID-certificate-if-you-were-vaccinated-abroad-procedure-for) indicates that the UK certificate is valid in France, but is unclear about other EU countries:

> If you have been vaccinated in one of the following countries –
> European Union Member States, Andorra, Iceland, Liechtenstein, Monaco,
> Norway, Switzerland, United Kingdom (England and Wales only) – your
> country issues an EU Digital COVID Certificate which is accepted in
> France, or, in the case of the United Kingdom, a digital format also
> accepted in France. In that case, you do not need to convert your
> COVID certificate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166758/are-there-countries-that-allow-tourists-to-obtain-the-eu-vaccination-certificate

Comment: @Anders that partially answers it, thanks for the link. That question covers non-EU residents in general, but the UK seems to be a weird edge case: UK certificates are valid in France (so the French government won't issue an EU certificate), but not across the EU.

Comment: Can you compare your app with the screenshots? the EU certificate should say UE. If you got a cert from before June 25 it might be possible to convert, but if you got 
a French one after June 25 they've made an exception for UK https://www.connexionfrance.com/French-news/How-to-update-Covid-vaccine-certificate-to-EU-format-via-TousAntiCovid

Comment: A simple way to determine this is to install one of the national checking programs (**VerificaC19** (Italy), **CovPassCheck** (Germany), **Covid Certificate Check** (Switzerland)) and read the UK QR-Code. At present, [15 non EU countries are supported (among them: Albania, Andorra, the Faroe Islands, Israel, Monaco, Marocco, Turkey and Panama)](https://ec.europa.eu/neighbourhood-enlargement/news/eu-digital-covid-certificate-commission-adopts-equivalence-decisions-albania-andorra-faroe_en).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.