# How can I get EU Digital COVID Certificate?

Tags: covid-19, eu, hungary, vaccinations, uzbekistan

I was vaccinated with AstraZeneca in Uzbekistan. I have a vaccination certificate. The vaccination certificate is accepted by Hungary and currently, I am studying in Hungary. Is it possible to get EU Digital COVID Certificate if I have been vaccinated not in the EU? If yes, how can I get it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there countries that allow tourists to obtain the EU vaccination certificate?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166758/are-there-countries-that-allow-tourists-to-obtain-the-eu-vaccination-certificate)

Comment: @Sneftel, unfortunately, this does not answer my question. It says the information is in Hungarian. Though this gives some hope as it is possible in some other countries.

Comment: Try reading this: [HUNGARIAN TOURISM AGENCY: Information on the EU Digital COVID certificate](https://visithungary.com/articles/information-on-the-eu-digital-covid-certificate-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went to the nearest [Kormanyablak](https://kormanyablak.hu/hu/kormanyablakok) with my printed vaccination certificate from Uzbekistan and filled the form which they provided. The next day, they sent EU digital COVID certificate to my e-mail.

Comment: make sure the data is also entered into your national healthcare services systems so if and when a national "vaccine passport" app is available you can use it if you want or need to. It's a problem I live with in the Netherlands right now, I was vaccinated before the systems were set up to exchange that information, so now the organisation maintaining the vaccination database for said app doesn't know I'm vaccinated, and the organisation that did the vaccinations isn't allowed to give them that information under EU privacy directives (which btw I fully support, though it's rather inconvenient)