# Vaccine certificate and passport name mismatch

Tags: germany, covid-19

My vaccine certificate has been issued in my married name (as this is how I am registered with my doctor), but my passport and all other ID is in my maiden name.
I'm flying to Germany from the UK and wondering whether they will accept my vaccine certificate if I also show my marriage certificate?

Comment: What is your citizenship? Which airline are you booked with, what did they say when you asked them about this?

Comment: I'm German (dual national, but travelling on German passport), travelling with Lufthansa who said it would be up to German Border Police to decide and that I should contact them before travel! Not the most helpful response from an airline I expected more from.

Comment: @exd Independent of citizenship, it should be of no surprise to any one that the COVID-19 regulations can change on day by day basis in any country. This makes it difficult for a third parties (in your case Lufthansa) to update their data (incuding all employees) based on the information found at: [BMI - Bevölkerungsschutz - Coronavirus](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/DE/themen/bevoelkerungsschutz/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html).

Comment: @exd Therefore: [Hilf dir selbst, so hilft dir Gott](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilf_dir_selbst,_so_hilft_dir_Gott) or [God helps those who help themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_helps_those_who_help_themselves), from Wikipedia, is advised reading.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is, after arrival in Germany, is to go to an Apotheke and get an **EU Vaccination Certificate** issued (which would be issued against your passport/id) if they are satisfied that everything is ok. (Showing your marriage certificate will definitely be helpful)

Make sure that your **name and birthday** on the issued certificate matches that in your **passport/id**!

The certificates are issued independent of citizenship or residence status and are free of charge.

An Apotheke will more likely know how individual national certificates from other countries looks like. The yellow *International Certificate of Vaccination* booklet should be no problem at all, since they are commonly used here.

Not all Apotheke issue these certificates, but one can be easily found here:

- [Apothekensuche | Mein Apothekenmanager](https://www.mein-apothekenmanager.de/apothekensuche?language=en)

  - enter *postal code* (or city name, address)

    - look for **COVID-19 Zertifikat** in the list

If you supply them with your email address, they will also send you a PDF of the certificate (otherwise you may only get it in a paper form).

Installing the **CovPass** application, which can also create a PDF, beforehand would also be a good idea, since then you only have to read/scan in the QR-Code of the printed **EU Vaccination Certificate**. An English version may be installed when downloaded from non German stores or on non German language phones/tablets (haven't tried this myself, so confirmation would be nice).

The application can store certificates for multiple peaple.

For the relevant German legal text for the issuing of the *EU Digital COVID Certificate*, see my answer at: [Are there countries that allow tourists to obtain the EU vaccination certificate?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/166771/95267).

---

When restaurants checked at all (I, personally, have never been checked up to now), most of those checking will more likely accept something they are familiar with. They are also supposed to check that the name and birthday matches that in the passport/id.

Fines for them could range anything between € 1000 to € 5000.

Comment: Will the airline even allow boarding?

Comment: @Mark Johnson I don’t know specifically for travel to Germany but AFAIK airlines **are** required to check that a traveller has *all* the necessary paperwork for entry. That typically includes evidence of Covid health status, at least it does when consulting Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130829/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-johnson-vaccine-certificate-and-passport-name-misma).