# Travelling between countries in the schengen area with vaccination proof that's accepted but not part of EU covid certification?

Tags: schengen, public-transport, tourist-visas

I'm travelling from India to France for tourism (double vaccinated with Covishield), and travelling to other countries from there which also accept the same. Curious, how hard or tricky has it been to travel between such countries? I'm wary about officials who aren't aware of the rules and create problems.

Citizenship - India

Residence - India

Time of Departure - 25th November to Paris

Vaccination Status - Two Doses, Covishield

Countries intended to travel: France, Netherlands, Greece, Italy

(Flights or trains are the form of transport)

France, Netherlands, and Greece allow Indian tourists to come, and no quarantine required for Covishield. I reckon both France/Switzerland will be able to issue us a Covid pass via TousAntiCovid or Swiss Covid Certificate.

Italy maintains people who have travelled to India in last 14 days are allowed for business reasons, but not travel.

By the time we reach Italy, it will be beyond 14 days in Europe, so very confusing what rule applies then.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the citizenships, countr(y)(ies) of residence, time in the departure countr(y)(ies) and travel destinations of the people involved. Countries have different and varied rules, which are constantly changing. I have voted to close as "Needs more focus."

Comment: You should be more wary about the checking being done **within** each country, such as in restaurants etc. Assume a waiter will not know what the vaccination documents issued in other countries will look like.

Comment: Citizenship isn't relevant but the other info and especially which countries in the EU your friends want to visit and how they will get there would be very useful.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I've updated the question with all the necessary details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Travel between France on the one hand, and the Benelux, Switzerland, or Italy on the other hand is almost unrestricted, aside from the occasional self-report locator form. Officials unaware of the rules isn't a huge issue as I would not expect to meet any official.

For Italy, there is a website where you have to report a bunch of information including the countries you have been to in the last 14 days. Formally, this doesn't directly answer your question but it suggests that only the last 14 days count and should alleviate some of your concerns.

One big restriction is that while driving is allowed, taking a train or bus leaving from France requires an EU Digial COVID certificate (and not merely a recognised vaccine). Airlines also sometimes ask for it. It also seems to be required to enter Italy. I would therefore [strongly recommend getting that certificate beforehand](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166758/are-there-countries-that-allow-tourists-to-obtain-the-eu-vaccination-certificate).

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. The two countries that we are going to that give a certificate beforehand are France and Switzerland. Switzerland charges 30 euros for it, and France closed down its service for non EU citizens last week. I think you can still get it in person from very select pharmacies in Paris, but that feels too risky to me. Might just opt for the Swiss one.