# Do restrictions exist for vaccinated Canadians travelling in Portugal?

Tags: covid-19, portugal

I'll be travelling to Portugal over the holidays, leaving on December 18 and returning on January 2. I'm a fully vaccinated Canadian with Canadian proof of vaccine. I will have a PCR test before travel to Portugal. Will that be sufficient to visit hotels and restaurants in Portugal during my trip? I don't have an EU COVID Digital Certificate. Information I can find online is conflicting. Some says an EU Covid Digital Certificate is required to visit tourist establishments and restaurants. Other sites say an EU Covid Digital Certificate or proof of vaccination.

Will my Canadian proof of vaccination stored on my phone and negative PCR test prior to departure be sufficient? If not what else is required to visit hotels, and restaurants during my stay.

Comment: When are you due to travel? You’ll need a mandatory negative test (even for vaccinated) when accessing bars and clubs, which will anyway be closed 2-9 Jan https://www.visitportugal.com/en/content/covid-19-measures-implemented-portugal

Comment: Related - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166758/are-there-countries-that-allow-tourists-to-obtain-the-eu-vaccination-certificate

Comment: @Traveller I've updated my question with the dates. I'm leaving on the 18 and returning on the 2nd. I will have a PCR test before I leave as it's a requirement for flying in Canada and entering Portugal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.